# Linearising an Equation with a Boundary Condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am considering the linearisation of a divergence-type equation for $\phi$

$\text{div} (\phi q),$

where $q$ is a particular $1$-form.  In PDE theory, given some base (or equilibrium/steady state) solution $\phi_0$, the linearisation of this PDE around $\phi_0$ is obtained by plugging in $\phi = \phi_0 + \epsilon \phi_1$, then only keeping terms of order $\epsilon$.

Does the base solution which one chooses to take the linearisation around also have to be consistent with boundary conditions?  In this case, there is a boundary condition that $\phi \rightarrow 1$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$.

Does this mean that one cannot take the base solution to be $\phi_0 = 0$ because this is inconsistent with the boundary condition?  How does the linearisation work if one does not know the base solution explicitly and has only proved its existence?

Comment: Typically the coefficients will depend explicitly on $\phi_0$ anyway, and so you won't be able to calculate the equation for $\phi_1$ without knowing what $\phi_0$ is. In any case the question of whether the BCs need to be satisfied exactly throughout the perturbative hierarchy is "generally things work better if you do but it is possible to proceed such that the BCs are only satisfied in an asymptotic sense".

Comment: I mean here only that the solutions are linearised, not that the actual operator is linearised if that makes sense.

Comment: I am a bit confused then, can one not write down a linearisation of a PDE if one does not know an explicit ''equilibrium'' solution already?  What is the point in having the concept of a linearisation in that case, if one typically wants to linearise a PDE which has nasty non-linearities and so does not have any explicit solutions?

Comment: Your phrasing is indicating a little bit of confusion. There is in fact a concept of linearizing around an equilibrium. This needs to be an exact equilibrium solution to the nonlinear problem so that there is any hope that the linearization gives a reasonable description of the *dynamic* problem for initial data near the equilibrium point.

Comment: (Cont.) But in other contexts, you may carry out linearization by solving a simplified equation which has some terms removed and then replacing those terms with perturbations. Again the base solution does need to solve *something* but what it solves will generally not be the original equation. For something like your setting, taking $\phi_0=0$ and then asking what $\phi_1$ is is just the same as trying to solve the original equation from scratch without using perturbation theory at all.

Comment: ''But in other contexts, you may carry out linearization by solving a simplified equation which has some terms removed and then replacing those terms with perturbations. ''  Is there an example of this online that I could see?

Comment: The type of linearisation I was discussing was the one mentioned in the answer of this thread, I may have got confused though https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4351750/linearisation-of-a-quasilinear-elliptic-pde/4353006?noredirect=1#comment9109723_4353006

Comment: The simplest possible case is in algebraic equations. Think of something like finding the larger solution to $x^2-x-\epsilon=0$. The "base solution" is the actual solution when $\epsilon=0$, which is $1$. Now you think of $x=1+x_1 \epsilon$ which yields $1+2x_1\epsilon+x_1^2 \epsilon^2-1-x_1\epsilon-\epsilon=0$, so by discarding the $\epsilon^2$ you get $x_1=1$, so that the first order approximate solution is $x=1+\epsilon$. Generally it is conceptually the same sort of thing in PDEs.